# UART doesn't work on BeagleBoneBlack running Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, beagleboneblack, uart

I have been working for a few days trying to get the `UART1` port to work on a bbb.  I flashed the prebuilt kernel from the `elinux wiki` (http://www.elinux.org/BeagleBoardUbuntu#Flasher), and the `UART1` appears in the `/dev` folder (as `/dev/ttyO1`, with a capital "o" not a zero), but when I write to it, nothing comes out of the pins.  I can use `UART0` (on a separate little serial header, but not the one I need) without any trouble.

I see a lot of tutorials for enabling UART1 that deal with a folder called `/sys/devices/bone_capemgr.*` but I don't have one.  I think it is because I have a newer kernel, and nearly all of those tutorials are exclusively for older kernels (<=3.8).

I read that the current 3.13 images from Robert C Nelson don't have a cape-manager (https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/beagleboard/ND3_w7_dn8Q), and you can use the "really simple cape manager" (https://github.com/RobertCNelson/rscm), but the `build.sh` script doesn't work on my `3.14 kernel`.  I tried to change a path in the script to fix it and now that bbb won't boot.

I also tried the beaglebone-universal-io script (
https://github.com/cdsteinkuehler/beaglebone-universal-io) but when I query the relevant pin:

`sudo ./config-pin -q P8_26`

I get the error:

`P8_26 pinmux file not found!
Please verify your device tree file`

Am I missing something really simple here?

Comment: How have you verified that no data is being sent?

Comment: Yes, I have an oscope hooked up to it.  I see the data coming from UART0 but nothing at all from UART1.  Or UART2 or UART5, actually.